# WPF Combo Box get and set data

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I use WPF with MVVM. The issue is i have Model class say Person contains three properties PersonID, Name, Job. The View Model contain `Person` class. The View contains `ComboBox` for `Job` and i entered the values staticaly in XAML using `ComboBoxItem` say Engineer, Lawyer,Doctor : now i need the combo box which is bound to `Person.Job` property to display the job of the person when the view display certain person and be able to enter/change the job and the new value to be submitted to person (i.e. i want to use the combo box like that one in MS Access forms)
Thanks in advance.
here XAML code for `ComboBox`

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Person, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
   SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Job, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
   SelectedValuePath="PersonID" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding Person.Job, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
   Width="50" Height="20" 
   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left">
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Engineer"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Lawyer"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Doctor"/>
</ComboBox>
```

The Job is displayed properly in the combo box but when saving new or modified value i get "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Engineer" in the Database how to correct this.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `Person.Job` is a `string`, does not have an ID and you want to keep your job list static try setting up your `ComboBox` like this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Job, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
       <x:Array Type="sys:String" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
           <sys:String>Engineer</sys:String>
           <sys:String>Lawyer</sys:String>
           <sys:String>Doctor</sys:String>
       </x:Array>
   </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Problem in your case is that you your `Job` is a `string` and you define `ComboBox` items as `ComboBoxItem` which means that `SelectedItem` will be of a `ComboBoxItem` type and when you select one WPF does a convertion which in this case means calling `ToString()`, hence your data. In the example above you set `ItemsSource` to array of strings which is wrapped by WPF in `ComboBoxItem` for presentation but `SelectedItem` will be of a `string` type

Comment: :One more help: how to use validation with such combobox using SelectedItem, i tried but validation not working.

Comment: what do you want to achive?

Comment: take a look at [`Binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors.aspx)

Comment: i use IDataErrorInfo for validation in the Model class (Person), the above combobox replaced a textbox where validation was working ok. but with combobox where binding through SelectedItem it is not working though i used ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True

Comment: I don't uderstand "ComboBox replaced TextBox". It was, and still is `ComboBox` and I don't see any validation code in your XAML. Which part of `Person` do you validate? On that `ComboBox` you can only validate `Job` and if your `Person` class implements `IDataErrorInfo` and `person["Job"]` returns an error, when invalid, then `SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Job, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"` should solve your issue

Comment: I mean originally in my application i used a textbox to display the Job field then i replaced it by this ComboBox. but any way i found the problem, it was in the Combobox style. i appreciate you help very much, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Notify a change to the binding on the combobox when a change on Person is notified.

PS It would be easier to answer with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle static binding by this method easily

**Xaml Code**

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  SelectedItem="{Binding PaymentType}"  Width="150" Grid.Column="1" Margin="50,4,0,0" Grid.Row="9">
                <ComboBox.Items>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Cash Payment"  />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Cheque Payment"  />                
                </ComboBox.Items>
 </ComboBox>
```

**View Model Code**

```
    private System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem _PaymentType;
    public System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem PaymentType
    {
              get
              {
                  return _PaymentType;
              }
              set
              {
                  _PaymentType = value;
                  RaisedPropertyChanged("PaymentType");
              }
    }
```

Now you can use variable **PaymentType** as

```
string output = PaymentType.Content.ToString();
```